# Kendo UI Tabstrip - Javascript - Tabs appear appended when content is SVG

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I have simple use of kendoTabStrip as shown here http://dojo.telerik.com/ISUvE

```
    <script>
    var index = 1;
    function newTab() {
        index++;
        var tabstrip = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");
        tabstrip.append({ text: index, content: '<div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="74" height="24" viewBox="0 0 74 24"><path fill="#4285F4" d="M9.24 8.19v2.46h5.88c-.18 1.38-.64 2.39-1.34 3.1-.86.86-2.2 1.8-4.54 1.8-3.62 0-6.45-2.92-6.45-6.54s2.83-6.54 6.45-6.54c1.95 0 3.38.77 4.43 1.76L15.4 2.5C13.94 1.08 11.98 0 9.24 0 4.28 0 .11 4.04.11 9s4.17 9 9.13 9c2.68 0 4.7-.88 6.28-2.52 1.62-1.62 2.13-3.91 2.13-5.75 0-.57-.04-1.1-.13-1.54H9.24z" /><path fill="#EA4335" d="M25 6.19c-3.21 0-5.83 2.44-5.83 5.81 0 3.34 2.62 5.81 5.83 5.81s5.83-2.46 5.83-5.81c0-3.37-2.62-5.81-5.83-5.81zm0 9.33c-1.76 0-3.28-1.45-3.28-3.52 0-2.09 1.52-3.52 3.28-3.52s3.28 1.43 3.28 3.52c0 2.07-1.52 3.52-3.28 3.52z" /><path fill="#4285F4" d="M53.58 7.49h-.09c-.57-.68-1.67-1.3-3.06-1.3C47.53 6.19 45 8.72 45 12c0 3.26 2.53 5.81 5.43 5.81 1.39 0 2.49-.62 3.06-1.32h.09v.81c0 2.22-1.19 3.41-3.1 3.41-1.56 0-2.53-1.12-2.93-2.07l-2.22.92c.64 1.54 2.33 3.43 5.15 3.43 2.99 0 5.52-1.76 5.52-6.05V6.49h-2.42v1zm-2.93 8.03c-1.76 0-3.1-1.5-3.1-3.52 0-2.05 1.34-3.52 3.1-3.52 1.74 0 3.1 1.5 3.1 3.54.01 2.03-1.36 3.5-3.1 3.5z" /><path fill="#FBBC05" d="M38 6.19c-3.21 0-5.83 2.44-5.83 5.81 0 3.34 2.62 5.81 5.83 5.81s5.83-2.46 5.83-5.81c0-3.37-2.62-5.81-5.83-5.81zm0 9.33c-1.76 0-3.28-1.45-3.28-3.52 0-2.09 1.52-3.52 3.28-3.52s3.28 1.43 3.28 3.52c0 2.07-1.52 3.52-3.28 3.52z" /><path fill="#34A853" d="M58 .24h2.51v17.57H58z" /><path fill="#EA4335" d="M68.26 15.52c-1.3 0-2.22-.59-2.82-1.76l7.77-3.21-.26-.66c-.48-1.3-1.96-3.7-4.97-3.7-2.99 0-5.48 2.35-5.48 5.81 0 3.26 2.46 5.81 5.76 5.81 2.66 0 4.2-1.63 4.84-2.57l-1.98-1.32c-.66.96-1.56 1.6-2.86 1.6zm-.18-7.15c1.03 0 1.91.53 2.2 1.28l-5.25 2.17c0-2.44 1.73-3.45 3.05-3.45z" /></svg></div>' });
    }
    $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataContentField: "content",
        dataSource: [
          { text: index, content: '<div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="74" height="24" viewBox="0 0 74 24"><path fill="#4285F4" d="M9.24 8.19v2.46h5.88c-.18 1.38-.64 2.39-1.34 3.1-.86.86-2.2 1.8-4.54 1.8-3.62 0-6.45-2.92-6.45-6.54s2.83-6.54 6.45-6.54c1.95 0 3.38.77 4.43 1.76L15.4 2.5C13.94 1.08 11.98 0 9.24 0 4.28 0 .11 4.04.11 9s4.17 9 9.13 9c2.68 0 4.7-.88 6.28-2.52 1.62-1.62 2.13-3.91 2.13-5.75 0-.57-.04-1.1-.13-1.54H9.24z" /><path fill="#EA4335" d="M25 6.19c-3.21 0-5.83 2.44-5.83 5.81 0 3.34 2.62 5.81 5.83 5.81s5.83-2.46 5.83-5.81c0-3.37-2.62-5.81-5.83-5.81zm0 9.33c-1.76 0-3.28-1.45-3.28-3.52 0-2.09 1.52-3.52 3.28-3.52s3.28 1.43 3.28 3.52c0 2.07-1.52 3.52-3.28 3.52z" /><path fill="#4285F4" d="M53.58 7.49h-.09c-.57-.68-1.67-1.3-3.06-1.3C47.53 6.19 45 8.72 45 12c0 3.26 2.53 5.81 5.43 5.81 1.39 0 2.49-.62 3.06-1.32h.09v.81c0 2.22-1.19 3.41-3.1 3.41-1.56 0-2.53-1.12-2.93-2.07l-2.22.92c.64 1.54 2.33 3.43 5.15 3.43 2.99 0 5.52-1.76 5.52-6.05V6.49h-2.42v1zm-2.93 8.03c-1.76 0-3.1-1.5-3.1-3.52 0-2.05 1.34-3.52 3.1-3.52 1.74 0 3.1 1.5 3.1 3.54.01 2.03-1.36 3.5-3.1 3.5z" /><path fill="#FBBC05" d="M38 6.19c-3.21 0-5.83 2.44-5.83 5.81 0 3.34 2.62 5.81 5.83 5.81s5.83-2.46 5.83-5.81c0-3.37-2.62-5.81-5.83-5.81zm0 9.33c-1.76 0-3.28-1.45-3.28-3.52 0-2.09 1.52-3.52 3.28-3.52s3.28 1.43 3.28 3.52c0 2.07-1.52 3.52-3.28 3.52z" /><path fill="#34A853" d="M58 .24h2.51v17.57H58z" /><path fill="#EA4335" d="M68.26 15.52c-1.3 0-2.22-.59-2.82-1.76l7.77-3.21-.26-.66c-.48-1.3-1.96-3.7-4.97-3.7-2.99 0-5.48 2.35-5.48 5.81 0 3.26 2.46 5.81 5.76 5.81 2.66 0 4.2-1.63 4.84-2.57l-1.98-1.32c-.66.96-1.56 1.6-2.86 1.6zm-.18-7.15c1.03 0 1.91.53 2.2 1.28l-5.25 2.17c0-2.44 1.73-3.45 3.05-3.45z" /></svg></div>' }
        ]
    }).data("kendoTabStrip").select(0);
</script>
```

Now, when I click for new tab, new tab gets stacked on previous tab. Example, I tab1 has SVG content and I created new tab. New tab with SVG content appears fine but 1st tab has content from 2nd tab as well.
Am I doing something wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are calling `kendoTabStrip()` every time the `newTab()` function is called. Thus creating a new TabStrip widget every time the function is called.

You have to change the line

```
//create new kendoTabStrip and get reference
var tabstrip = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");
```

to

```
//get reference only
var tabstrip = $("#tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip");
```

I've updated your [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AWiNe/2).

Comment: This is perfect! I did not realize this mistake. My week end is saved.